# Does this table warrant an index?

Tags: mysql, performance, refactoring, indexing, uuid

Hello again Stackoverflow...

My organization is using SugarCRM for internal process handling. We are in the process of importing approx. 27Gig worth of MsSQL data into select tables. As I was working along one of the tables called accounts_contacts is an intermediary table linking 'accounts' to 'contacts' (surprise). HEre is the table structure:

Name        Type        Collation       Null    Default
id      varchar(36) utf8_general_ci     No  None
contact_id  varchar(36) utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL
account_id  varchar(36) utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL
date_modified   datetime                    Yes NULL
deleted     tinyint(1)                  Yes 0

Demo data:

0001391a-9d28-4bd0-9cec-f469cd244ca7    19135ac7-d47c-e111-b389-1cc1dee8bacd    1a135ac7-d47c-e111-b389-1cc1dee8bacd    0000-00-00 00:00:00 0

000262b6-a0ef-48de-b0f6-47db097b35d6    43080e24-a24d-e111-8cf6-1cc1dee8aa73    44080e24-a24d-e111-8cf6-1cc1dee8aa73    0000-00-00 00:00:00 0

00042aa7-39cd-4fcb-9f47-dc2b31c69a11    e9764a4d-d921-e111-8e18-1cc1dee8bacd    ea764a4d-d921-e111-8e18-1cc1dee8bacd    0000-00-00 00:00:00

At the moment said table rests at approx. 55k rows.

My question: for speed and performance, at what point would this table warrent an index of contact_id and account_id?

Comment: Did you mean MS SQL instead of MySQL, above? You mention MS in your question but tagged it my?

Comment: Are you using innoDB? Are those contact_id and account_id foreign key references? If both of those questions are answered yes, then if those fields are indexed in the original table(s), additional indexing shouldn't be necessary. This assumes you are using mySQL, not MS SQL as you mention in the question.

Comment: @ahillman3: Are you kidding? WHat good is an index on one table of the two to be joined? Unless you mean something else.

Comment: I'm assuming both accounts and contacts _id field is indexed, and the intermediate table is properly using foreign keys to reference those columns. If it is not using foreign keys, then an index or two on the intermediate table is warranted.

Comment: @ahillman3: Ah, you mean that if a `FOREIGN KEY` is defined, then MySQL also adds an index (if there isn't one already). OK then.

Comment: @ypercube,ahillman3 Guys, the foreign key constraints do not make MySQL create a compound index on contact_id and account_id, do they? So joining accounts with contacts does not benefit from that?

Comment: @konstantin: Yes, if you want a compound index (or any other index that is not automatically created), you have to define it. I prefer to define all indices anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, a combined index on contact_id and account_id will give you immediate performance boost for joining accounts and contacts. The only reason for not adding an index to a table is the overhead of keeping the index in sync on table data inserts/updates. So if you have many writes to that link table, you should benchmark the effect on an index. Otherwise, if you mostly just read from that table - create an index.

Comment: Aye, insert/updates would be in the minority of operations. Reads are performed overwhelmingly more often. TY for the information.